# Unique User Role Report WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, user-roles, woothemes

Two questions involved in my quagmire:

1. Where do I find 'report functionality' in the woo themes plugins?
2. How do I implement reporting for a custom user role in the orders section (the custom user role has already been created in WP?

Example:
`sales by date | sales by product | sales by 'custom user role here'`

Answer (score 0):

Solution for Query 1:

The report functionality can be assessed from front-end via WooCommerce->Reports as shown in the following image

[image]

The backend of this functionality comes from the **Package WooCommerce/Admin/Reports** i.e. within the file structure of 
**/woocommerce/includes/admin/reports/**

Solution for Query 2:

WooCommerce doesn't provide "sales by 'custom user role here'" by deafult but you can code so or you can use [Woocommerce Order Report Snapshot](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-csv-export-for-user-roles/) plugin to get roles specific reports